# Dynamically generating the layout of a skill tree

Tags: algorithm, graph

How would I go about automatically generating the layout of a skill tree?

Skill tree nodes have at least one parent, but they can have more. Ideally I'd have a root node that recursively creates its branches.

I've attached a basic sketch of the desired result (the white node is supposed to be the root node).

[image: Hypothetical skill tree layout]

Comment: Is this question about generating the logical topology of the graph itself or is it about how to visualize it?

Comment: If you already know which nodes your graph will contain and which ones you want to connect, the problem of mapping that abstract structure into a 2D image is called **Graph Drawing**, and there are lots of algorithms and library implementations to help — [Wikipedia has a good overview here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing#Layout_Methods). If you don't yet know the nodes/connections they should have, then we'll need a bit more guidance to suggest good algorithms for that aspect.

Comment: I like [this text from Tollis, Di Battista, Eades, Tamassia](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?kn=0133016153) on the topic; I'm happy to pick through it on your behalf if you can provide more details. If you can, consider doing the layout arrangement as you generate the skill tree - it can be easier to make a nice looking planar graph as you go rather than make a graph & try to find a nice planar layout. And no algorithm is going to be perfect, especially with regards to aesthetic.